# magento database connectivity

Tags: magento

i want to take  magento database backup on localhost

for that i have write following php file but  can't got magento connection

```
<?php // magento database connection
$conn=mysql_connect("host","username","password") or die("sorry to connect".mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("db_name",$conn) or die('db error');
?>

<?php
//this is a reference query for export data in csv

$query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/wamp/www/magento/catalog_product_entity.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  FROM catalog_product_entity";

echo $query;

$rs = mysql_query($query,$conn);
$data = mysql_affected_rows($rs);
echo $data;

?>
```

LOAD DATA INFILE 'catalog_product_entity.csv' INTO TABLE table_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
?>

answer my query.
all give me another solution.

Comment: Please specify what exactly goes wrong and what the problem is. Where does `$conn` come from?

Answer (score 1):

There are already Magento modules for this task:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/centerax/extension/2927/automatic-db-backups

Answer (score 0):

Magento has a built in database backup utility, which, by default, can be triggered by going to System > Tools > Backups in the Magento Admin. Rather than rewriting this functionality, it would be much more efficient to simply locate the class/method used there and simply call that instead.